# Installing software from source on Linux and filename expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames

installing from source some software on Ubuntu, [with some shell script](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/blob/release-v3.6.0/scripts/build-js1/build-js1-linux.sh), I end up with the following error..

```
vagrant@precise64:~/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0$  bash -x ./scripts/build-js1/build-js1-linux.sh werror=no
 ...
+ make x64.release werror=no
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out'
+ popd
+ local outputDir=/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/../../src/libs/x64/ubuntu-12.04
+ [[ -d /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/../../src/libs/x64/ubuntu-12.04 ]]
+ pushd /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/../../src/EventStore.Projections.v8Integration/
+ local outputObj=/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/../../src/libs/x64/ubuntu-12.04/libjs1.so
+ g++ -I '/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/include *.cpp' -o /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/../../src/libs/x64/ubuntu-12.04/libjs1.so -fPIC -shared -std=c++0x -lstdc++ -Wl,--start-group '/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_{base.x64,nosnapshot.x64}.a' '/home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicu{i18n,uc,data}.a' -Wl,--end-group -lrt -lpthread
g++: error: /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_{base.x64,nosnapshot.x64}.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicu{i18n,uc,data}.a: No such file or directory
vagrant@precise64:~/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0$
```

Although if I try to see if those files exists, they do :

```
vagrant@precise64:~/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0$ ls -la /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_{base.x64,nosnapshot.x64}.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1162178 Mar  1 13:24 /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.x64.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    3580 Mar  1 13:25 /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_nosnapshot.x64.a
```

and

```
vagrant@precise64:~/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0$ ls -la  /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicu{i18n,uc,data}.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant    338 Mar  1 13:29 /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicudata.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 314000 Mar  1 13:27 /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicui18n.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 147746 Mar  1 13:29 /home/vagrant/EventStore-oss-v3.5.0/scripts/build-js1/v8/out/x64.release/obj.target/third_party/icu/libicuuc.a
```

Is there anything obvious linux principle I am missing ... ?

Could filename expansion be interpreted differently when used in a script and when used on the command line ?

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://askubuntu.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Good Luck.

Comment: @shellter  what makes you think so ? you think it might be ubuntu specific ? I have no clue. if its my use of ubuntu in the title i'll change  that

Comment: someone else voted to close. I have no idea how this would relate to ubuntu more than fedora or anything. if you have indication that's the case, please share your clue.

Comment: you must have noticed that Qs get either get answered right away, or they don't get anything. I'm just trying to point you to where I think you might get some help (IMHO). I can't spend time debating it with you, but I wish you Good Luck solving your problem.

Comment: no time either, hence I like to understand. thank you